# Vector rejection in only one direction

Tags: vectors

This is vector rejection:

[image: Vector rejection]

But, in my case, **b** is a unit vector, so we can remove the divisor, and we get

**a2 = a - b(a dot b)**

Now, for the problem, this will reject **a** in both directions, what if I only want to reject it in b's direction forwardly, and not also backwardly?; Say **b = (0, 1)** and **a = (0, 200)**, then it should work, but not if **a = (0, -200)**

So I've thought about this, and since I am doing this in a programming language I used the max function:

**a2 = a - b * max(a dot b, 0)**

This actually works pretty nice, but isn't there a real "mathematical" way to do this, because I feel like this is a bit cheaty..?

Comment: It's not cheaty at all. It would still be mathematical if you wrote a case distinction $$\mathbf a_2=\begin{cases}\mathbf a-(\mathbf a\cdot \mathbf b)\mathbf b&\text{if }\mathbf a\cdot \mathbf b>0\\\mathbf a&\text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen So is this the correct mathematical way to do it?

Comment: Also I forgot it was the max not the min sorry, edited